# Css doesn't work for a custom fxml component

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I use the following CSS to change the font of some components which are placed on a custom JavaFX `AnchorPane`, defined as `fx:root`. But the `font-size` remains default.

```
* {
    -fx-font-family : Arial;
}
.label, .textField, .textfield,  .checkBox, .text{
    -fx-font-size: 18;
}
```

I got that I should change them using the ids of all inner components but it's not a good idea, because it results in redundant code.

Then I got that applying it on the main style class, it will work. But the sad story is  that `*` can't be overriden.  (I have defined `*` selector in a global css class for my whole application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `.root` instead of *.

For the font size, some of your class names are wrong. Try

```
.label, .text-field, .check-box, .text {
    -fx-font-size: 18pt ;
}
```

Style classes are documents in the [CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Note that `Text` nodes have empty style class, so you need to explicitly set the style class for your text nodes.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. 18pt works well but I got to use 14pt because with 14pt which was quite the same size. what is pt and when should I use it?

Comment: Point size is the traditional unit for font size (it predates computers). [Here's a reasonable source](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) from a random google search.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I shouldn't use pt!